# i2c clock speed is varying depending on used resource

Tags: python, i2c

I am having problems with my i2c bus speed on a Raspberry Pi 4. My Sensor requires clock stretching, which I set according to [these instructions (https://pypi.org/project/scd30/)

When I check the bus typing `$sudo i2cdetect -y 1`
I see the following:
[image: i2cdetect zoomed out]

[image]
So first question is: why does the clock speed switch from 25ms to 10ms? The default speed should be 10ms, shouldn't it?

When I send commands over the i2c tools in the command line, the speed is 25ms
`$i2cset -y 1 0x61 0x01 0x04 i`, but when I use a pythonscript the clock speed is 10ms
:

```
from smbus2 import SMBus, i2c_msg

msg1 = i2c_msg.read(0x61, 18)
read_measurement = i2c_msg.write(0x61, [0x03, 0x00])
bus = SMBus(1)
bus.i2c_rdwr(read_measurement, msg1)
data1 = list(msg1)
print(data1)
```

Lowering the bus speed with `dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=50000` as described [here](https://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2018/02/change-raspberry-pi-i2c-bus-speed/) has no effect on my bus speed.

My Problem is that my sensor gives me constant values for the measurements, which is probably due to a high clock speed (datasheet says 12ms is needed). Using ic2tools seems to achieve this with a clockstretch, but that doesn't work within the python script...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Set a slow I2C bus rate, e.g.

`dtparam=i2c_arm=on,i2c_arm_baudrate=50000`

This will set a bus rate of 50 kbps (or 20 ms per bit in the slightly odd terms you appear to be using).

Comment: I already tried lower values (edited my post), it is not affecting the observed bus speed at all

Comment: That is the problem then.  You need to sort out the bus speed problem first.  Are you using a non-standard OS?

Comment: I am using the latest 32bit version of raspbian.